# Creating Empty Documents in Firestore

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I understand that empty documents within collections are removed automatically by the system in Firestore. However, I have a situation now where the name of the document serves a purpose. I have a collection named usernames, and within this, many documents with the ID being the username. For instance, usernames/bob_marley is what I might see in the database. The problem here is that, since the documents do not have any fields in them, they get removed automatically thereby defeating the purpose of the set-up. How should I be structuring my database in these cases?

Thank you

Comment: Empty documents are not deleted by the system. From this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65604748/2783654

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The easiest thing to do is simply not allow the document to ever become empty.  Keep one property in it with (for example) "exists = true" and make sure it never gets removed.  Use a security rule to prevent this, if you're concerned about users accidentally doing this to themselves.

Another thing to do is re-evaluate what exactly you're trying to do with an empty document in the system, and if it's worthwhile to think about how to structure your data in a way that best meets the queries you want to perform.

Comment: Good catch Doug - my answer was for Realtime Database. I deleted it - Doug's here is correct.

Comment: Jus a simple follow-up question: I know the fields are indexed automatically, but are document names indexed as well?

Comment: Document names must be unique, and an index definitely is required to enforce that.

Comment: But in Cloud Firestore, the document names are indexed automatically right?

Comment: Yes, they *have* to be, otherwise the system would be horribly inefficient at something as simple as finding a document by its name.

Comment: Right XD. Thank you a lot of your input!