# Are empty documents in Firestore deleted?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I read [in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48758395/creating-empty-documents-in-firestore) that empty documents will be deleted in Google Firestore.
Is this still true? I have empty documents in one of my collections, they've been there for months, so I guess is not true (anymore).
Can anyone enlighten me?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Nope, there is nothing in place to automatically delete empty documents, as you might have a valid reason for wanting those empty documents to exist.

That said, I'd typically recommend putting a dummy field into a document that you create, even if you have no use for that field. The reason for that is that some tools *may* reject empty documents or not store them. But there's nothing on the database itself that does this, and I can't even call out any of such tools at the top of my head right now.

Comment: Just to add something, one of "such tools" could be octabyte's fireo, an ORM for Firestore. It seems like it would not store empty documents.