# Firestore: do I really need to check document existance for query results?

Tags: php, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Firestore [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#php_3) recommends checking document for existance. What is the case for document to not exist if it was queried from the database?

```php
$citiesRef = $db->collection('cities');
$query = $citiesRef->where('capital', '=', true);
$documents = $query->documents();
foreach ($documents as $document) {
    if ($document->exists()) {
        printf('Document data for document %s:' . PHP_EOL, $document->id());
        print_r($document->data());
        printf(PHP_EOL);
    } else {
        printf('Document %s does not exist!' . PHP_EOL, $snapshot->id());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

It's true that all documents returned by a query do exist. The checks for existence are useful when you get a document directly.

`$collection->document('anything')` will always return a document reference, whether the document exists or not, so you can use `exists()` to determine how you want to proceed with that document.

Answer (score 1):

There is no case for a document not to exist if it appeared as the result of iterating over an existing snapshot (citing [Creating Empty Documents in Firestore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48758395/creating-empty-documents-in-firestore)).

I suspect this is an oversight in the documentation. `$db->collection('cities')` is an example of something that actually could be non-existent (in theory), although the example code does not check that.